# Make a specific file only accessible to the server

Tags: php, cron, file-permissions

I have a file called backup.php that creates a backup .sql file of my db and saves it to my folder "backups"

I have set up my backups folders file permission to: 700. So now, the backup files  files cannot be accessed by a web browser, and I have to get them via ftp. Which is good.

I also tried setting my backup.php to the file permission: 700, but I can still run the script by going to the page.

So, my question is, how can I restrict people from running my script and only allow a cron job from my server to run the script?

Comment: `if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !== '127.0.0.1'){die('no access');}` ? (`127.0.0.1` being local, could probably also try the server ip)

Comment: Ah, yes, that would work perfect with the servers ip I think. Thanks.

Comment: Need me to put it as an answer? :)

Comment: If you want the points, then yes. ;)

Comment: Sure why not haha :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just need to check if the IP trying to access the file is the server, otherwise stop it.

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !== '127.0.0.1'){
    die('no access');
}
```